# Annotation CrossOrigin not working in Spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, axios

I have a Spring Boot application that exposes some endpoints. From a React app I want to make requests to these endpoints, but it keeps giving me CORS problem:

> access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/dashboard/clients?page=0&size=30'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

So I've tried using `@CrossOrigin` annotation for all my methods and also for the Controller class, but the error is the same.
The get request in my react app looks like this:

```
constructor() {
        this.url = 'localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/dashboard/clients?page=0&size=30';
    }

    getProjectStatusById(projectId) {
        Axios.get(this.url).then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }
```

What's missing?

**EDIT**
In my spring boot app I have only this class to configure security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Autowired
    SysdataUserDetailsService sysdataUserDetailsService;



    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint jwtAuthEntryPoint;



    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(sysdataUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PathConstants.USER_AUTH +"/**", PathConstants.HELIOS+"/dashboard/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_INSTANCE+"/**").permitAll()
                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // custom jwt filter.
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have String Security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it by overriding `addCorsMappings` of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, so either create a class that *extends* `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` or define a bean in your configuration class like this:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                        .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit**

As of 5.0 `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated and hence you could acheive the same thing by implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` interface (added  default methods, thanks java 8 ! and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "OPTIONS")
                    .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                    .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                    .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
   }
 }
```

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Comment: @Dseaster thanks for your reply, you can see my edit

Comment: Hi, I've tried your new solution but it doesn't work. Are the allowedHeader and exposedHeaders necessary to specify?

Comment: @Usr Did you manage to get it working? I have the same problem in none of solution all over Stack Overflow nor Spring docs worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create separate CORS configuration class as follows. This class will handle the CORS configurations for all requests throughout your application and you need not annotate each controller separately with `@CrossOrigin`.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");         //'*' allows all endpoints, Provide your URL/endpoint, if any.
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");         
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");   //add the methods you want to allow like 'GET', 'PUT',etc. using similar statements.
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to call the method somewhere or will it do everything by itself since it's @Configuration ? Because I added the class but it's not working :\

Comment: @Dseaster You need not call the method anywhere. It will do everything by itself.

Comment: Ok, but it's not working... Keeps giving me the error. I've copied your code and added all methods I need

Comment: @Dseaster Each method type goes in a separate statement. I have edited the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I've added them like that

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global configuration like

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }
```

Just use this to add a global corrs configuration that will affect all the endpoints.Try this if the annotation doesn't work.