# Angular/Spring with cors mapping added - blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have a simple Angular app that perform a post request to an endpoint this way:

```
login(username:string, password:string){

   return this.http.post<String>('localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/auth/login',{
    "username": username,
    "password":password
});
}
```

but the error of CORS policy is thrown. In my Spring application, that is the one the expose the endpoint, I've set the cors mappings this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
       public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET","POST", "OPTIONS");
       }

}
```

I've encountered the same problem but with another application, [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904200/annotation-crossorigin-not-working-in-spring-boot), got the response and used it correctly. Now with this angular project it doesn't work. Do I have to change something?

**EDIT**
This is my controller in Spring Boot

```
@CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION)
    @ApiOperation("Login into Helios administrational console.")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> autenticate(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        Authentication auth = authManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(auth);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthResponse(token));
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was in the url: it wanted a `'http://localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/auth/login'`, so with http. Stupid error.
Now I have a new one.
It says:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So I've added:

```
.allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
```

and in angular

```
 this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'})
      };

   return this.http.post<String>('http://localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/auth/login',{
    "username": username,
    "password":password
}, this.httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: check this https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#javaconfig

Comment: you have to allow headers "allowedHeaders" also "allowedOrigins", plz show us your controller.

Comment: Edited with the controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
public httpOptions;

login(username:string, password:string){
 this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': <some data> })
    };

   return this.http.post<String>(
    'localhost:9090/helios-admin/api/auth/login',
    { "username": username, "password":password },
    this.httpOptions
 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your method but didn't work. Also, for my login request I don't need any authorization, so I've deleted that part. Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Hi,  I've updated the question because there is a different problem.

Comment: @Dseaster Did you test the api from POSTMAN ?

Comment: @Dseaster So error is defiantly from angular side. Can you try like this write this line just before the this.http.post
`headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');`

Comment: @Dseaster Can you replace the data type `String` to `any` in post api request

Comment: Hi, I've already added the solution you proposed, where do I have to do the append? headers exists only inside httpOptions

Comment: @Dseaster. Welcome 

Answer (score 1):

Add **@CrossOrigin** annotation before the rest api controller class method.

Example

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBean> postUserLogin(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shalika, I've updated the question because there is a different problem.

Comment: This answer solved my CORS problem. Thank you @Shalika

Answer (score 0):

You should add config to Spring to allow CORS

I made like this:

**java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
    }
}
```

Another ways for spring u can see here. Good luck

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors