# Internal Server Error When Adding WebMvcConfigurer To Spring Boot Rest Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a Spring Boot app and I wanted to allow other origins to make requests because I got the 'cors' error. So I searched and I found this answer: [Annotation CrossOrigin not working in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904200/annotation-crossorigin-not-working-in-spring-boot) witch helped for the endpoints that have no body. On the other hand, those who have a body I get `Internal Server Error`.

[image]

Below is the configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:63343", "http://localhost:3000", "https://smart-booking-ba548.web.app")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT");
    }
}
```

The controllers have the `@RestController` annotation and the methods `@Get/Post|Mapping`. They return a `ResponseEntity<Object>`.

Comment: can you put a reproducer in github ?

Comment: I solved it, below is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the following method in main class.

```java
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```